# react-native package android.support.v4.media does not exist

Tags: android-support-library, react-native, support-v4

I am using react-native 0.57.1
react-native track player 0.2.5
I have got following error:

> C:\zzzprojects\app\node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\src\main\java\guichaguri\trackplayer\metadata\Metadata.java:9:
>   error: package android.support.v4.media does not exist import
>   android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
>
> ^
>   C:\zzzprojects\app\node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\src\main\java\guichaguri\trackplayer\metadata\Metadata.java:10:
>   error: package android.support.v4.media does not exist import
>   android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat;
>
> ^
>   C:\zzzprojects\app\node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\src\main\java\guichaguri\trackplayer\metadata\Metadata.java:11:
>   error: package android.support.v4.media.session does not exist import
>   android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver;
>
> ^
>   C:\zzzprojects\app\node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\src\main\java\guichaguri\trackplayer\metadata\Metadata.java:12:
>   error: package android.support.v4.media.session does not exist import
>   android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat;

^
...........
...........
..........

> C:\zzzprojects\app\node_modules\react-native-track-player\android\src\main\java\guichaguri\trackplayer\metadata\components\CustomVolume.java:14:
>   error: cannot find symbol super(canControl ? VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE :
>   VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED, maxVolume, (int)(volume * maxVolume));

^
***symbol: variable VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE
location: class CustomVolume***
**Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get** full output
100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
```

**Execution failed for task ':react-native-track-player:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.**

```
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 43s
36 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 11 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have tried a lot of methods I even init a new project and just install react native it is giving same error again .
...
thanks.
do answer me soon

Comment: thanks @rajanmishra can you help with issue too.i have  raised issue but they dont seem to bother......https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/301